# JSON Parse Error: Unexpected Identifier "undefined" in Titanium-based iOS Application

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

I am facing an issue while running my Titanium-based iOS application (version 4.4.05) on Titanium SDK 12.1.2.1e3a7d3afb. The app is unable to load the *index*.json file, which leads to a "SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier 'undefined'" during the JSON parsing process.

```
Reading stylesheet from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/05C15C26-F859-4066-9F91-C4F956FC95F9/Advisor.app/stylesheet.plist

2023-07-19 11:49:14.794068+0530 Advisor[6841:1971119] [ERROR] Could not load _index_.json require index, error was File not found

2023-07-19 11:49:14.889741+0530 Advisor[6841:1971119] [INFO] Advisor 4.4.05 (Powered by Titanium 12.1.2.1e3a7d3afb)

2023-07-19 11:49:14.905497+0530 Advisor[6841:1971119] [ERROR] /ti.kernel.js:1073

          fileIndex = JSON.parse(json);

                                 ^

SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"

    at parse ([native code])

    at filenameExists (/ti.kernel.js:1073:33)

    at require (/ti.kernel.js:757:36)

    at doLoad (/ti.main.js:12870:34)

    at loadBootstrapScripts (/ti.main.js:12893:11)

    at loadAsync (/ti.main.js:12898:23)

    at  (/ti.main.js:12916:10)

    at load (/ti.kernel.js:634:24)

    at  (/ti.kernel.js:1107:18)




    Foundation 0x00000001cb5531ec _NSDescriptionWithLocaleFunc + 80

    CoreFoundation 0x00000001d12c44a4 4230C122-42E8-383B-BEEC-EE7B61F8BB61 + 332964

    CoreFoundation 0x00000001d12f71d4 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsReturningMetadata + 184

    CoreFoundation 0x00000001d12f3aac _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 44

    TitaniumKit 0x0000000101719ce8 TiLogMessage + 52

    TitaniumKit 0x00000001017492e0 -[TiExceptionHandler reportScriptError:] + 60

    JavaScriptCore 0x00000001e4e3b11c C9852269-BF5A-3150-AFED-2D50892B6D4B + 4796700

    JavaScriptCore 0x00000001e49a9980 C9852269-BF5A-3150-AFED-2D50892B6D4B + 6528

    TitaniumKit 0x0000000101729adc -[KrollBridge evalFileOnThread:context:] + 340

    TitaniumKit 0x00000001017539e0 -[KrollInvocation invoke:] + 52

    TitaniumKit 0x00000001017542e4 -[KrollContext invoke:] + 84

    TitaniumKit 0x000000010172a2f4 -[KrollBridge didStartNewContext:] + 1084

    TitaniumKit 0x00000001017549bc -[KrollContext main] + 988

    libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000101448520 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32

    libdispatch.dylib 0x000000010144a038 _dispatch_client_callout + 20

    libdispatch.dylib 0x000000010145a798 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1196

    libdispatch.dylib 0x000000010145a2dc _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44

    CoreFoundation 0x00000001d130bc28 4230C122-42E8-383B-BEEC-EE7B61F8BB61 + 625704

    CoreFoundation 0x00000001d12ed560 4230C122-42E8-383B-BEEC-EE7B61F8BB61 + 501088

    CoreFoundation 0x00000001d12f23ec CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
```

Checked the existence of *index*.json file in the expected location: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/05C15C26-F859-4066-9F91-C4F956FC95F9/Advisor.app/. The file seems to be present.

Verified file permissions and access rights to ensure the application can read the file.

Reviewed the code that attempts to load and parse *index*.json to ensure it handles cases where the file may not be found or contains unexpected data gracefully.

Examined preceding logs and error messages to gather additional context, but no relevant information was found.

Comment: can you please add a `console.log(json)` before the parse line. It looks like it just contains `undefined`. And is ` Could not load _index_.json require index, error was File not found` your error message? So the file was not found but you are still trying to parse the json?